# sort users in view by amount of nodes created in drupal 6

Tags: views, 6, users

Here at Drupal Answers I found [how to do it in drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1709/using-views-how-to-list-users-and-have-the-number-of-nodes-created-by-theme) though but obviously I need it for a D6 site.

So far I haven't found any filter in my view settings that will allow to do this, nor ar relationship that similar as D7 in D6.

UPDATE: Looked a bit more into the question about the drupal 7 version of this issue. Seems like that question is only about mentioning the amount of nodes created in the view, not using that amount as a sort criterium. Looks like we're still at square one....

Comment: It works for me quite the same way as described in the D7 question.  Make sure you are using Views 3 and that grouping is enabled.

Comment: Of course I forgot that D6 has also got a version 3 of views. This got me a little bit closer. Step 4 of the answer of the D7 question seems missing from the D6 version. In views3 of D6, I checked "User: content authored". The form that follows has only two fields and a checkbox ("Administrative title", "Label" and "Require this relationship" respectively). That's all that's containeed in this relationship, even after submitting aforementioned fields. There are no multiple fieldsets as mentioned in the D7 question linked above, leave alone there would be something about "Use grouping".

Comment: I am sorry, bit difficult to help as my system is not set to English.  Anyway I try, just do not take the names literally: Relationship settings are ok.  The "Use grouping" is in my case in the second box "advanced settings" (beneath base settings for the view and above the Style settings of the view).  Once it is enabled, you can just add the Node-Id field and select an aggregation function.  Works also as a sort-criterion.

Comment: Thanks for that I found the grouping thing. I now started noticing that in the drupal 7 question, the goal isn't to sort the users according to nodes created but to simply mention the amount of nodes that users have created. I guess that's for a different question altogether....